# Как вывести тег title из файла.php

Tags: php

**Не могу добиться вывода title на shtml-страницах из файла.php.**
**На странице, открытой в браузере - или пустой тайтл, или отображается сам код**

Пишу в shtml:

```js
<title><!--#include virtual="/title2.php" --></title>
```

Пробовала также:

```
<title><?php include("title2.php"); ?></title> ,
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
```

И создаю тот самый файл title2.php:

```js
<?php

$titleList = array(
 '/dlit-ssi-11-2' => 'Эксперимент',
 '/'  => 'Тайтл для главной',
 '/dlit'  => 'Тайтл для dlit'
 ......
 );

 
 $title =& $titleList[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']];
 echo $title ?? "Тайтл для отсутствующего пункта";
?>
```

Файл со скриптом привязан в head.

В .htaccess пробовала добавить .shtml. Безрезультатно.
На сервере работает связка Apache+Nginx
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 ()
nginx version: nginx/1.14.1

Хостер спрашивает: "Уточните, какие требования нужны для работы вашего скрипта, мы проверим все ли настройки, компоненты присутствуют. "

А я ни малейшего представления об этом не имею.
Подскажите, где я ошиблась? 
Или чего не хватает для отображения title хтмл-страниц из файла.php?

Comment: Как-то не доводилось работать с shtml, но есть подозрение что дело в том, что вы в html (shtml) пытаетесь включить через SSI php файл. Обычно, чтобы php код в файле мог выполняться, файл должен иметь расширение php (то есть тот файл, в который вы включаете php код). Но конечно же это все может зависеть и от конфигураций

Comment: Алекс, спасибо. Вроде бы для этого требуется, чтобы вся страница html/shtml выполнялась как php. Вчера мучили со службой поддержки .hraccess, чтобы этого добиться После добавления туда строки AddType application/x-httpd-lsphp .html .html .shtml стили сломались. Пришлось ее закомментировать. Так и не знаю, что делать.

Comment: А важно чтобы страница, в которую вы включаете ваши php скрипты, имела расширение именно .shtml? Нельзя ее просто в php переименовать? А насчет стилей - стоит попробовать поиграться со слешами в путях к стилям (добавить/убрать). Как выглядят пути к стилям?

Comment: Да, эти страницы собираются из ssi-включений. Стили починила, оказалось, что пути к файлам.css были относительными. Видимо, в этом причина была.   Вот, возвращаюсь к своим тайтлам